# How can I return two different values from the same column in a SQL Join?

Tags: oracle, join

I'm trying to write a query for a Reimbursement System that retrieves a single Request based on the ID. The query joins three other tables for the User, request Type, and request Status, joining on their foreign keys within the Requests table, but I'm trying to join the User table twice to pull two different names.

My query is posted below:

```
SELECT ers_reimbursements.*, 
   ers_users.u_firstname AS author_fname, ers_users.u_lastname AS author_lname,
   ers_users.u_firstname AS resolver_fname, ers_users.u_lastname AS resolver_lname,
   ers_reimbursement_type.rt_type, ers_reimbursement_status.rs_status
FROM ers_reimbursements
INNER JOIN ers_users ON ers_users.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_author
INNER JOIN ers_users ON ers_users.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_resolver
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_type ON ers_reimbursement_type.rt_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_type
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_status ON ers_reimbursement_status.rs_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_status
WHERE ers_reimbursements.r_id = 2;
```

And the resulting view is:

```
R_ID | R_Amount | R_Description| R_Submitted | R_Resolved | U_ID_Author | U_ID_Resolver | RT_Type | RT_Status | Author_FName | Author_LName | Resolver_FName | Resolver_LName | RT_Type_1 | RS_Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2    | 100      | AVS          | 31-DEC-17   | 1-JAN-18   | 3           | 2             | 1       | 2         | James        | Mitchell     | James          | Mitchell       | Travel    | Approved
```

In the view, the Author's ID is 3, and the Resolver ID is 2. 3 belongs to James Mitchell, and 2 belongs to Alan Martin, but both the Author and Resolver Name columns show "James Mitchell," when it should show the Resolver as "Alan Martin."

Why is it using James' name twice? How can I get both James' and Alan's names to show up in the result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an alias to refer to the `ers_users` table if you are joining on it more than once.

In the example below, `ers_users` is aliased as 'A' first to get the author's name, and then as 'R' to reference it in order to retrieve the resolver name.

```
SELECT ers_reimbursements.*, 
   A.u_firstname AS author_fname, A.u_lastname AS author_lname,
   R.u_firstname AS resolver_fname, R.u_lastname AS resolver_lname,
   ers_reimbursement_type.rt_type, ers_reimbursement_status.rs_status
FROM ers_reimbursements
INNER JOIN ers_users A ON A.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_author
INNER JOIN ers_users R ON R.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_resolver
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_type ON ers_reimbursement_type.rt_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_type
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_status ON ers_reimbursement_status.rs_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_status
WHERE ers_reimbursements.r_id = 2;
```

Comment: EDIT: Nevermine, I had to replace the ers_users after the ON clause with the aliases. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the joins to distinguish them from each other and use the aliases in the field references:

```
SELECT ers_reimbursements.*, 
   author_users.u_firstname AS author_fname, author_users.u_lastname AS author_lname,
   resolver_users.u_firstname AS resolver_fname, resolver_users.u_lastname AS resolver_lname,
   ers_reimbursement_type.rt_type, ers_reimbursement_status.rs_status
FROM ers_reimbursements
INNER JOIN ers_users AS author_users ON ers_users.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_author
INNER JOIN ers_users AS resolver_users ON ers_users.u_id = ers_reimbursements.u_id_resolver
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_type ON ers_reimbursement_type.rt_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_type
INNER JOIN ers_reimbursement_status ON ers_reimbursement_status.rs_id = ers_reimbursements.rt_status
WHERE ers_reimbursements.r_id = 2;
```

Comment: SQL Developer is throwing a Syntax error by the "ers_users AS author_users" line, under author_users.

    Syntax Error. Partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams)

Comment: @Sonic260 Sounds like it may be a little different for SQL Developer than for straight MySQL. The other answer (which you accepted) doesn't have the "AS".